# Visual Studio unable to include QT files

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2010

I am using QT 4.7.1 and VS 2010.

I have installed QT and VS add-in and its demo project which works fine.

When I try to build another code that uses QT files, it shows the following error:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QPixmap': No such file or directory

Do I need to enter some directory information in VS? Thanks for help

Comment: This would indicate that the project isn't configured correctly. Perhaps look at the working project and compare that project's `Include` directories to the project that cannot find the file.